# Log4J failover appender with HTTP appender

Tags: log4j, log4j2, failover

So I am using the failoverappender with as primary a HTTP appender.  The FailoverAppender docs state:

*The FailoverAppender will capture exceptions in an Appender and then route the event to a different appender.*

I could not find any documentation however when the HTTPappender will actually throw an exception. So what I was wondering is if my HTTP post request returns a 4XX or 5XX code will this actually throw a log4j  exception and activate the failover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if a `4xx` or `5xx` status code is returned, the failover appender will be used.

Which exceptions are thrown by `HttpAppender` depend upon the implementation of [`HttpManager`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/HttpManager.html) in use. Right now the [`HttpURLConnectionManager`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/HttpURLConnectionManager.html) is hardcoded into Log4j, which relies upon your system's implementation of [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) implementation.

A `4xx` or `5xx` status code is one of the reasons the standard `HttpURLConnection` in OpenJDK throws an exception (cf. [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dfacda488bfbe2e11e8d607a6d08527710286982/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#L1991)).